How to interpret a branching fraction diagram?
I'm confused as to how can I (student in master 1 class of particle physics) interpret such diagram:

Where $q^2 = m^2(l^+l^-)$. I understand that the y  axis represents the variation of the probability of the disintegration $B^+ \to K^+ l^+ l^-$, but what does $m^2(l^+l^-)$ represent ? Does $m^2(l^+l^-)=m(l^+)m(l^-)$?
I understand that the disintegration can be represented by such Feynman diagram:

But how does the two relate and how can we explain both peaks at $q^2 \sim 9.50 \; GeV^2$ and $ q^2\sim 13.50 \; GeV^2$?

That notation is unclear; could it be the invariant mass (squared) of the lepton pair, which is called "W" in my sector: $W^2 \equiv (p^{\mu}++p^{\mu}-)^2$?
